# Script "7 days log tar and then remove the 7 days logs and exclude the tar file after next 7 days"

Tags: scripting, logs, tar, zip

I am trying to create a script such that it could tar.gz all the previous log of per 7 days log and exclude the tar file in next run.

Is the script ok or should I have to make a change

```
find /home/bankex/bankex/glassfish/domains/bankex/logs/ -mtime -7 -print0 | xargs tar -czvf /home/bankex/bankex/glassfish/domains/bankex/logs/oldlogs_$(date +"%Y%m%d").tar.gz --exclude=/home/bankex/bankex/glassfish/domains/bankex/logs/*.tar.gz --null
find /home/bankex/bankex/glassfish/domains/bankex/logs/server.log* -mtime -7 -delete
```

Comment: Create a playground directory with some files that can be deleted and try your commands. This will probably show some problems. Read the documentation of the `find` and `xargs` commands. `find ... -print0` | needs `xargs -0`. This combination might not do what you want if you have many files which will cause `xargs` to run the command several times.

Comment: There is a linux utility called "logrotate" that comes with most GNU/Linux OS and can easily compress and rotate logs. You only need to create a file in /etc/logrotate.d/ with the desired configuration and restart the daemon. You can take a look at the "CONFIGURATION FILE" section in "man logrotate". I know you want to create a script, but I just thought that maybe you didn't know this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 find /home/bankex/bankex/glassfish/domains/bankex/logs/ -maxdepth 1 -mtime -7 -type f ! -name "*.tar.gz" |  xargs tar -czvf /home/bankex/bankex/glassfish/domains/bankex/logs/oldlogs_$(date +"%Y%m%d").tar.gz --remove-files
```

- `maxdepth` levels of directories
- `type f` only files
- `! -name` excludes the file with pattern `.tar.gz`
- `--remove-files` will remove files which are tared

Comment: Dear sir, i need to exclude the server.log file too as it has to be static and should remain there to create log

Comment: @TheStoryTellerNepal you can add another exclude name

Comment: -mtime should it be +7?